# Firefox Addon Reading Local XPI, File and Directory Listing

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

Following a chat in #amo-editors, I was wondering if the following are possible from a Firefox Addon:

1. Opening a local XPI for reading
2. Listing all files in above XPI with their sizes
3. Reading selected files

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely possible.

1 + 2) Have to use nsIZipReader to read the xpi. This gives you all files within it.

3) To read contents you have to use zip readers `getInputStream` function and then wrap it in stream instance, then read it with argument of `entry.realSize` as `read` on stream takes characters to read.

[MDN :: nsIZipWriter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIZipWriter)

[MDN :: nsIZipReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIZipReader)

---

edit: i was curious. i think i got it. heres example of how to make it dump contents of a zip (list all files within). see the `console.log(entryPointer)` that spits out the "zip path". it also reads the contents of the files.

```
var zr = Cc["@mozilla.org/libjar/zip-reader;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIZipReader);
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');

var reusableStreamInstance = Cc['@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableInputStream);

//var pathExtFolder = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.profileDir, 'extensions');
var pathToXpiToRead = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.profileDir, 'extensions', 'PortableTester@jetpack.xpi');
var nsiFileXpi = new FileUtils.File(pathToXpiToRead);

//Services.ww.activeWindow.alert(pathToXpiToRead);

try {
  zr.open(nsiFileXpi); //if file dne it throws here
  var entries = zr.findEntries('*');
  while (entries.hasMore()) {
    var entryPointer = entries.getNext(); //just a string of "zip path" (this means path to file in zip, and it uses forward slashes remember)
    var entry = zr.getEntry(entryPointer); // should return true on `entry instanceof Ci.nsIZipEntry`
    console.log('entryPointer', entryPointer);
    /* CONSOLE OUTPUT
     * "entryPointer" "bootstrap.js" Scratchpad/1:18
     */
    console.info('entry', entry);
    /* CONSOLE OUTPUT
     * "entry" XPCWrappedNative_NoHelper { QueryInterface: QueryInterface(), compression: Getter, size: Getter, realSize: Getter, CRC32: Getter, isDirectory: Getter, lastModifiedTime: Getter, isSynthetic: Getter, permissions: Getter, compression: 8 } Scratchpad/1:19
     */
    if (!entry.isDirectory) {
        var inputStream = zr.getInputStream(entryPointer);
        reusableStreamInstance.init(inputStream);
        var fileContents = reusableStreamInstance.read(entry.realSize);
        console.log('contenst of file=', fileContents);
    } else {
        console.log('is directory, no stream to read');
    }
  }
} catch (ex) {
  console.warn('exception occured = ', ex);
  if (ex.name == 'NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND') {
    Services.ww.activeWindow.alert('XPI at path does not exist!\n\nPath = ' + pathToXpiToRead);
  }
} finally {
  zr.close();
  console.log('zr closed');
  //Cu.forceGC(); //im not sure shoud i do this here?
}
```

I'm not sure if I should do a `Cu.forceGC()` in the finally, maybe @nmaier can advise us on that.

I'm also not sure if I handled reading the input stream properly, it works, but i dont know memory wise. I did `.read(entry.realSize)` first time doing this.

variable viewer on `entry`:
[image: variable viewer on <code>entry</code>]

Comment: "I'm not sure if I should do a Cu.forceGC() in the finally, maybe @nmaier can advise us on that." Don't use `.forceGC()` if you don't have to. Not sure why you'd want to do that anyway?! Anyway, you'll get my +1 once you remove the unrelated bits that don't even attempt to answer the question like "I haven't read from zip but i have written text directly to a zip..."...

Comment: The way I'm reusing the stream instance is that ok? Should I do a `reusableStreamInstance.close()` in the `finally{}`? I forgot about that I just got carried away with coding and appending to this post :P I took it out

Comment: Also is there a better way to do my exception test for if not found flag?

Comment: Actually, answers are supposed to, well, answer questions, not ask new ones?! :p Anyway: You shouldn't reuse streams (stream wrappers); that kinda violates the contract, even though it works in this instance. You should close the inputStream (or scriptable stream wrapper around it) from `zr.getInputStream()`. `zr.open()` should be outside of the try-finally block, but in another (outer) try-block. And so on. Might be a good idea to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Haha it's just that I think this answer could be better. I'm learning while helping others. I can get things to work but I don't know how things are going on under the hood and if they break. I'll post this code there thanks man.

Comment: Thank you Noitidart. I gather this is a code example form something else. What does `'PortableTester@jetpack.xpi'` doing? Also is the directory listing recursive?

Comment: It's just the name of an xpi of an add-on i have installed, change it to the name of any add-on xpi file in your extensions folder. To figure out your extensions folder go to scratchpad and paste this: `alert(OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.profileDir, 'extensions'))`

Comment: See [CodeReviewer :: Improvements to nsiZipReader and nsIScriptableInputStream](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/56824/49106) for implementation by @nmaier it's very interesting and the `try-catch` is done properly, because if `zr.open` does not open then it will throw error on the `zr.close` and my snippet above doesn't catch that. The input stream is also properly used. It also uses fewer interfaces, like no need for `FileUtils.jsm` and `OS.File.jsm`. Has some bonus on exception logic too, real nice.